# A more optimized code in recursion exercise

Tags: python, recursion

As a novice programmer doing an exercise in recursion, the following function takes in two numbers and returns a comma-separated string with all the numbers in-between the start and end number, inclusive of both numbers. I used a list, convert it to set and at last convert again to string.The code working but I believe that there is a better way to solve it. Any suggestions?

```
def numbersInbetween(a, b):
    if a > b:
        return "Invalid"
    elif a == b:
        return str(b) 
    else:
        alist = range(a,b+1,1)
        aset = set(alist)
        aset2 = ','.join(str(s) for s in aset)
        numbersInbetween(a+1, b)
        return aset2
```

Comment: You never do anything with the return value of the recursive call to `numbersInbetween` - why?

Comment: Why the conversion to `set`?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I used recursion because exercise asks it. Furthermore, I used set because when  I converted list to string the autograder said that my answer was wrong. So I used this way. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to use `range`, there is no need to do recursion at all :-)

```
def numbersInbetween(a, b):
    if a > b:
        return "Invalid"
    elif a == b:
        return b
    else:
        return "{}, {}".format(a, numbersInbetween(a + 1, b))

print numbersInbetween(1, 10)
# 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

We recursion to generate the string from the next element till the end with this line

```
return "{}, {}".format(a, numbersInbetween(a + 1, b))
```

We retain the current number `a`, and then we call the same function again with `a + 1` and `b`. So the evaluation will be done like this, for the input 1 and 3

```
{}, {}.format(1, numbersInbetween(2, 3))
```

and then

```
"{}, {}".format(1, "{}, {}".format(2, numbersInbetween(3, 3)))
```

which will become

```
"{}, {}".format(1, "{}, {}".format(2, 3))
```

which will become

```
"{}, {}".format(1, "2, 3")
```

and that finally becomes

```
1, 2, 3
```

Comment: @lejlot He does recursive calls but not using it. But this answer uses recursive calls.